# Glide is not loading properly on Android

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I am doing Popular-Movies project stage ONE! I have one problem by using Glide Library to load the picture from TheMovieDB API.

I am using a recylerview adapter to display my data model in a Grid layout. Everything works very well except by loading **some** posters into the Gridlayout that some of them haven't been loaded properly. Please take a look at my screenshot and let me know if you come up with some idea.

[image]

Comment: please post the code you are using to load images

Comment: 1) Check that does it has proper image url.  2) If it is high resolution images then resize it by calling `.override(width ,height)` and caching strategy.

Comment: May be image resolution is too high and you are implementing center crop or something. Please provide your code. You may try out "Picasso". It is more efficient in  some cases.

Comment: How to ask for help in stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried picasso, it shows fine, but with Glide I could not fix the problem. I will try to set  item view cache size on true. Let's see what happens! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

by adding "fixedsize" and "cachesize" to my recyclerview that solve my problem, but I think I have go to find that how I can solve the problem for the dynamic environment.

```
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
```